# Showing non-differentiability of a function at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

> Starting from a function $f:t\mapsto f(t)$ such that:
>
> - $f(0)=0\tag{1}$
> - $\liminf\limits_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t}f\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)=-\infty\tag{2}$
> - $\limsup\limits_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t}f\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)=+\infty\tag{3}$
>
> setting:
>
> - $f_l(t)=\liminf\limits_{\delta\to0} \dfrac{f(t+\delta)-f(t)}{\delta}$;
> - $f^u(t)=\limsup\limits_{\delta\to0} \dfrac{f(t+\delta)-f(t)}{\delta}$.
>
> I have to show that:
>
> 1. $f^u(0)=+\infty$;
> 2. $f_l(0)=-\infty$.

I succeeded in showing 1. by the following steps:
\begin{align}
f^u(0)=\limsup\limits_{t\to\infty} \dfrac{f\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)-f(0)}{\dfrac{1}{t}}&\geq\limsup_{t\to\infty}\sqrt{t}f\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)\\&=+\infty
\end{align}
with the inequality coming from $(1)$ plus the fact that $\dfrac{f\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{t}}=tf\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)\geq\sqrt{t}f\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)$ for $t\geq1$ and the last equality following from $(3)$.

---

---

However, I cannot show 2. (I have tried to show it by the same token used for showing 1., but I did not succeed). Could you please give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim \inf_{t \to 0} \frac {f(t)} t=\lim \inf_{t \to \infty} t f(\frac  1 t)\leq \lim \inf_{t \to \infty} \sqrt t f(\frac  1 t)=-\infty$. [The inequality follows from the fact that $f(\frac 1 t)<0, t>1$ implies $tf(\frac 1 t) \leq \sqrt t f(\frac1  t)$].

Comment: Why do you start from $f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)<0$? Is this due to the starting assumption $(2)$ (i.e. $\liminf\limits_{t\to\infty} \sqrt{t}f\left(\dfrac{1}{t}\right)=-\infty$)?

Comment: @Strictly_increasing $\lim\inf g(t)=-\infty$  means there is some sequence $t_n \to \infty$ such that $g(t_n) \to -\infty$. For this sequence $g(t_n) <0$ for $n$ sufficiently large.